# Contact Form 7: Change sender message

Tags: wordpress, contact-form-7

I want to display sender message as like

```
“Thank You <a href="link">Click Here</a> to download book”
```

in contact form 7 after form submit

Comment: my is working for you? Please check and replay your feedback.

Answer (score 0):

Add below code as per the screen shot and change url.

```
Create one thank-you page and add your html “Thank You <a href="link">Click Here</a> to download book”

on_sent_ok: “location = ‘//test.com/thankyou’;”
```

[image]

Hope this helps for you.